# Load a value into a register in LC3

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, lc3, immediate-operand

Is there a single LC3 instruction to load a value into a register? I need to write some assembly code and I come to where I need to write just a single instruction to store the value 1 in R1.

Answer (score 2):

```
LD R1, value
```

Do a .fill on "value" with whatever value you want to load into R1.
I don't believe there's a way to load a literal value into a register with a single line, but you can do it with one instruction and one label.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.
it is:
**LD R0,Param1**

What this means is that it will load the value of Param1 into Register 0.

Answer (score 0):

LC-3 doesn't have a move-immediate.  [The instruction set](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/fussell/courses/cs310h/lectures/Lecture_10-310h.pdf) includes AND/ADD/NOT (with register or immediate), LEA, and load instructions.

---

#### Using `add`-immediate with a zeroed register

If you have a zeroed register, you can materialize any small constant into a register with `add` (5-bit sign-extended immediate, value-range `[-16, +15]`).

(**Zero is special**: It can be created by AND regardless of previous register contents.)

```
 and  r7, r7, #0        ; R7 = 0.  Somewhere in your program or function

 add  r0, r7, #-16      ; R0 = 0 + -16 = -16
 add  r1, r7, #15       ; R1 = 15
```

The source register doesn't *have* to be zero; any other known constant within -16..+15 of your desired value can work.  e.g. if you know `R4` is `3`, you can get R1=1 with `add r1, r4, #-3 + 1`.  But that's complicated to keep track of, probably only worth doing if you're optimizing for size or speed.

---

#### Load a value from static storage

`ld` uses a PC-relative addressing mode so it can load nearby words (-256 .. +255).

```
  ld r1, ONE


ONE .fill 1        ; elsewhere in your program
```

If you need a couple simple constants at various different places in your program, and don't want to leave one of your precious few registers zeroed all the time, this is a single-instruction way to get a constant that doesn't require any setup.

---

#### LEA to create a non-zero value

If you want to just return 0 or non-0 from a function, you may not care *which* non-zero value you create.  `and` can only clear bits, not set them.
`add` and `not` aren't safe either if you don't know the value of any register; there's always an input that will result in `0` for them.  e.g. `add r0, r1, #1` wraps to 0 if the original value was 0xFFFF aka `-1`.

But LEA can create a value that depends only on the program counter (which is known) and the 9-bit signed immediate in the instruction ([-256 .. +255] range).  We know that address `0` isn't going to be in the middle of our program, so any address is fine if we just want non-0.  Often we begin LC-3 programs at `.orig x3000`, so small numbers like `1` can't be generated by LEA, but if we just need non-0 that's fine.

```
.orig x3000


...
 lea r0, nonzero
...


nonzero       ; put this label literally anywhere in your program
var1   .fill 1
```

The `nonzero` label is attached to the same address as `var1`, which is totally fine.  You could even put it on the LEA instruction itself, like

```
nonzero  lea r0, nonzero
```

If you can use a `.orig` that puts your program close to the start of memory address-space, small constants like `1` can be created with LEA.  Like perhaps

```
.orig  0
address0

...

  lea r1, address0+1       ; R1 = 1, if this is the right syntax for this

...
```